# how to write from linkedlist to a text file using java

Tags: java, filewriter

I wrote this code to write the nodes of this linked list to a text file, but it won't work with `FileWriter` whenever I try it with `System.out.println("n.ModelName");`

```
 public void modName() throws IOException{
     PrintWriter outputStream = null;
     outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\OsaMa\\Desktop\\Toyota.txt"));
     node n=head;

    while (n != null){
       if(n.Company.equalsIgnoreCase("Toyota")){
          outputStream.println(n.ModelName);
           n=n.next;
       }
       else{
           n=n.next;
       }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void modName() throws IOException{

     PrintWriter outputStream = null;
     outputStream = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\OsaMa\\Desktop\\Toyota.txt","UTF-8");
     node n=head;

    while (n != null){
       if(n.Company.equalsIgnoreCase("Toyota")){
          outputStream.println(n.ModelName);
           n=n.next;
       }
       else{
           n=n.next;
       }
        } 
    outputStream.close();

}
```

You need to close the stream once writing is done.

### See Also

- [How to create a file and write to a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitely call flush or close the outputstream to see the output in your file. So once you are done with writing the data to stream you just ask stream to flush the data to file like:

```
outputStream.flush();
```

Or if you close the stream like:

```
outputStream.close();
```

to close the stream and flush the data to file.

Reason you see output when you use sysout is internally does the following:

```
if (autoFlush)
    out.flush();
```

If you want the same functionality then define your PrintWriter as:

```
outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\OsaMa\\Desktop\\Toyota.txt"), true);//set auto flush on
                                                                                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was useful :D